# Get Windows 7 File Open Dialog to sort files by date

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Up until yesterday, when I opened a file in Notepad I could click on Date and the most recent file would show up at the top of the list in Details View. Suddenly, while still in Details, it shows the folders at the top and the files below, so I have to scroll to the bottom to see the most recent file. I am in Details view when this happens.

Why did it change? How do I change it back?

Answer (score 3):

You can switch to Details view which will let you click on the column headers again.  Click on the Date column header to sort by date.  Then you can switch back to list or thumbnail or whichever view you want.

[image: Explorer Views]

You can also switch between them by holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and scrolling your mousewheel while the folder/file list pane is active.

Comment: @techie007 Thanks, beat me to the screenshot

Comment: I was already making it when you answered. :)  Go Windows 7's Snipping Tool! ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already in Details. I can sort it by date when I click on the column header, but the problem is the file folders always showing up on top nowadays.

Comment: @Rich Are you clicking on it twice to do both an ascending and a descending sort?  When I try it via the dialog in Notepad I have to click the Date modified column twice to get the files to be at the top.

Comment: I can click the header multiple times, and it will sort the files oldest to newest or nesest to oldest as I click. But they'll always show up below the folder names.

Comment: i'm not surprised it works "correctly" for you. Until yesterday it worked "correctly" for me too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at one of your Windows 7 Libraries in the dialog (ie: `Documents`), instead of an absolute path (ie: `C:\foldername\`), then you get additional arrangement order options:

[image: Exploring Library]

If you have it set to `Arrange by: Folder`, then folders will always be at the top.

You can choose `Arrange by: Date modified` there (as well):

[image: "Arrange By" Options]